# Breaking up array WHILE

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

I'm implementing memcached on a site and I'm caching the results of a specific query, which is working great, but I am having problems putting together the code to set the variables I need to make the cache usable.

My array is as follows, which contains two groups of data:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 9126 [id] => 9126 [1] => Oh penguin, you so silly. [title] => Oh penguin, you so silly. [2] => November-01-2011-00-14-09-ScreenShot20111031at9.jpg [path] => November-01-2011-00-14-09-ScreenShot20111031at9.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 9131 [id] => 9131 [1] => Reasons you die... [title] => Reasons you die... [2] => November-01-2011-00-17-04-ScreenShot20111031at8.jpg [path] => November-01-2011-00-17-04-ScreenShot20111031at8.jpg ) )
```

I can set them manually, and call them like this:

```
$id = $clean[0][0];
$title = $clean[0][1];
$path = $clean[0][2];
```

But I am having problems writing a WHILE loop to go through and set the variables dynamically. I also tried a FOR EACH statement to no avail:

```
for each($clean as $image){
$id = $image->id;
$path = $image->path;
$title = $image->title;
echo "THIS IS YOUR FREAKING ID $id THIS IS YOUR TITLE $title THIS IS YOUR PATH $path";
}
```

Any insight?

Edit:

Solution was to not call them as objects, as pointed out, change to reference them like this:

```
$id = $image["id"];
$path = $image["path"];
$title = $image["title"];
```

Cheers.

Comment: @str added the FOR EACH that i attempted.

Comment: "No avail" is a bad problem description a.k.a. error message. But it seems you should read about arrays as you access them like objects instead.

Comment: Also, it's `foreach` not `for each`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just serialize the entire array before saving in cache, then unserialize when you retrieve from cache. Then just reference the values as you indicated.

Comment: the clean variable is the unserialized result `$clean = (unserialize($cachedResults));` by referencing it properly.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha! According to your updated OP, why are you referencing array elements using the object syntax? Instead of `$image->id` it should be `$image['id']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array( 
             array ( 0 => 9126, 
                     'id' => 9126, 
                     1 => 'Oh penguin, you so silly.', 
                     'title' => 'Oh penguin, you so silly.',
                     2 => 'November-01-2011-00-14-09-ScreenShot20111031at9.jpg',
                     'path' => 'November-01-2011-00-14-09-ScreenShot20111031at9.jpg' ),
             array ( 0 => 9126, 
                     'id' => 9126, 
                     1 => 'Oh penguin, you so silly.', 
                     'title' => 'Oh penguin, you so silly.',
                     2 => 'November-01-2011-00-14-09-ScreenShot20111031at9.jpg',
                     'path' => 'November-01-2011-00-14-09-ScreenShot20111031at9.jpg' )
);

foreach( $array as $row)
{
    // Based on your array, you can either do:
    echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['title'] . $row['path']. "\n";
    echo $row[0] . ' ' . $row[1] . ' ' . $row[ 2 ] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each should serve you well.  If you need to iterate through $clean as well just wrap around another foreach.

```
$arr =  $clean[0];
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $value; // or in your case set
}
```